# Format time difference between 2 date time vars in a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, datetime-format

I'm using Powershell to run an AWS backup to S3 buckets and write out a continuing log file. I need to show how long the backup takes in the log file. I've tried a number of methods and can't seem to find one that works. If I remove the -Format ... command it shows the time difference but it's ugly.  This code is one of my many attempts

```
$StartTime = get-date
>>> RUN THE BACKUP
$EndTime1 = Get-Date
$DURATION = $EndTime1 - $StartTime  -Format 'hh:mm:ss'
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use `ToString()` directly on the resulting `TimeSpan`, or use the `-f` string format operator:

```bsh
$duration.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss')
# or 
'{0:hh\:mm\:ss}' -f $duration
```

Comment: I'm sure I'm using it wrong. I tried both methods and got about the same result: 
    EndTime1 = Get-Date
    $DURATION = $StartTime - $EndTime1
    
    Write-Output "Crisma End Time: $EndTime1, Duration: '{0:hh\:mm\:ss}' -f $duration" >>"$LogFile

Comment: Yeah, you need to wrap the `-f` expression in `$()` to make it work inside an expandable string: `"Crisma End Time: $EndTime1, Duration: $('{0:hh\:mm\:ss}' -f $duration)"` :)

Comment: You might also want to qualify the other variable name: `"Crisma End Time: ${EndTime1}, Duration: $('{0:hh\:mm\:ss}' -f $duration)"`

Answer (score 0):

This working for me in Powershell:

```
Write-Host ('Elapsed time: {0:hh}h {0:mm}m {0:ss\.fff}s' -f $diff)
```

Giving:

```
Elapsed time: 00h 00m 05.359s
```

Or in cmd (With Delayed expansion), with same result:

```
powershell -command $Begin=Get-Date -date !Begin!; $End=Get-Date -date !END!; $diff=$End-$Begin; Write-Host ^('Elapsed time: {0:hh}h {0:mm}m {0:ss\.fff}s' -f $diff^)
```

Where !BEGIN! and !END! are set before like this:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=*" %%K in (`powershell -command Get-Date -format o`) do set END=%%~K
```